# Visual Studio Extension: Pass Selected Text to WPF Window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I've got a basic extension that - highlights text (currently an xml open tag ) and provides a context menu button which will open a WPF form.  What I'd love is an easy way to pass the content of ... to the form when the button is clicked (and back from the form later).  What would be fine as well is doing the same with selected text (select the text, hit the button on the context menu...).  The thing is, I can't find a reasonably easy way to pass text (selected or processed) to the form from the editor window to the form.

Is there an easy way to do this?